# Prompt for password when exiting presentation

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, screensaver

Is it possible to prompt for a password when exiting a full screen presentation in Microsoft PowerPoint?

I need to be able to show a presentation constantly, whilst leaving my computer, but do not want anyone else to be able to jump onto the computer while I am away.

I've looked into setting the presentation as a screen saver, but my company has default screen savers so cannot use this option.

I also looked into software which can display a presentation when a computer is locked, again company restrictions.

Only other option I can think of is to leave my computer un locked and running the presentation, but require a password to exit the presentation, is this achievable via a macro ?

In excel I would use a simple macro to protect/unprotect. not sure if this would work in PP.

Comment: You don't want to use PowerPoint to prompt for a password. It's trivial to force it to close, bypassing the VBA, for explore like example by pressing ALT+F4. Your question is suffering a bit from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Try editing it to ask how to solve your problem, not how to implement your proposed solution.

Comment: It'll probably be better to convert your PowerPoint to a video and then you could use/write an application that has the functionality you desire...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't possible as users could still exit the application via Alt + F4, or through Task Manager.

If the slideshow is being presented on an external display, then a possible solution is to *physically* protect the computer from being accessed by other people.

Answer (score 0):

Keynote has this feature, you could try finding an emulator to emulate Keynote as an app. Keynote can also open Powerpoint files so you don't need a converter whatsoever. If you ever forget your password, I found out a simple fix for that. You can find the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSQMrDLPPdg)

Answer (score -1):

There are methods for locking a computer when you are away.
Some of them are:

- Dynamic Lock on Windows 10
  Lets you lock your PC when your phone goes out of Bluetooth range.
  For more info see Microsoft's article
  [Lock your Windows 10 PC automatically when you step away from it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028111/windows-lock-your-windows-10-pc-automatically-when-you-step-away-from).
- [Lock My PC](https://fspro.net/lock-pc/)
  This free tool lets you override the default Windows lock screen (where other admins could still log in) by disabling the mouse and disc drives. You can trigger this lock with your own hotkeys, make the lock screen transparent, and even shut down or log off the user once the lock screen is up for a set time.
- [Predator](https://www.predator-usb.com/predator/en/index.php)
  Locks the computer using a USB stick as the key.